[react-places-autocomplete]: Google Maps Places library must be loaded
I have a GoogleMap component that renders the Map and if necessary; the markers.
            <GoogleMapReact
               bootstrapURLKeys={{key: import.meta.env.VITE_MAP_KEY, libraries: ['places']}}
                center={{lat: lat, lng: lng}}
                zoom={address ? 17 : 12}
                options={{
                    zoomControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    rotateControl: false,
                    fullscreenControl: false,
                    keyboardShortcuts: false,
                    clickableIcons: false,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    gestureHandling: 'none',
                }}
            >
                <Marker address={address} lat={lat + 0.00035} lng={lng - 0.0003}/>
            </GoogleMapReact>

Also I have a PlaceInput component that needs to be placed on the marker of the map when a place is selected.
const PlaceInput = ({finalAddress}) => {
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

    const handleChange = address => {
        setAddress(address);
        finalAddress(address)
    };

    const handleSelect = address => {
        geocodeByAddress(address)
            .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
            .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
    };

    return (
        <PlacesAutocomplete
            value={address}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onSelect={handleSelect}
        >
            {({getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading}) => (
                <div>
                    <input
                        {...getInputProps({
                            placeholder: 'Building',
                            className: 'location-search-input',
                        })}
                    />
                    <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                        // some code
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </PlacesAutocomplete>
    );
};

It's not a problem to pass the address from one component to another, but when I go to this page I get this error:
Uncaught Error: [react-places-autocomplete]: Google Maps Places library must be loaded. Please add `libraries=places` to the src URL.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any suggestions please

Have you added the <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>  as mentioned in the documentation? If you have, it seems the URL is not correct; if not, please try replace YOUR_API_KEY and add the 
From the documentation, you will need to load the library by adding
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>.
If you have already done that, the error says the URL is not correct. It is missing the &libraries=places part in your URL, you can probably see that in your web page using developer tools;
If you have not added it yet, please add the <script> tag into the <head> of your index.html and don't forget to replace the YOUR_API_KEY to your own API Key.
Since you are using Vite, please try to add this line to your index.html, just like the following:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <!-- ↓ ADD BELOW -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%VITE_MAP_KEY%&libraries=places"></script> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

